# Como crear numeros aleatorios gigantes en c (6 digitos o mas)

Tags: array, c, estructuras-de-datos

debo hacer una tarea donde debo rellenar un vector con distintas cantidades de datos, sin embargo mi idea es poder llenar este vector con numeros entre 0 a 2 millones, al poner la funcion el `printf("%d",RAND_MAX);` me sale que el maximo es 32.767 , como puedo aumentar esto? ya que el vector que intento hacer es de medio millon de datos, y la idea es que no se repitan tantas veces los mismos numeros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));
long TAMA=500000;
long *listamiles;
listamiles =  malloc( TAMA *sizeof (long int));

for (long i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++){
    listamiles[i] = rand()%2000000;
```

y hasta aca no se que hacer para que los numeros random esten entre 0 y 2 millones

Comment: No uses `rand()`, ya que te devuelve enteros. En cambio usa `drand48()` que te devuelve un `double` entre 0.0 y 1.0 (con 1.0 no incluído), luego puedes convertir este rango en el rango que necesites. Saludos

Comment: Como puedo incorporar en drand48() en el codigo? intente reemplazarlo pero no me compila, en la linea 6 puse ```double drand48(time(NULL));``` y en la linea 11 (la ultima) lo dejo como ```listamiles[i] = drand48() ``` y no me ejecuta

Comment: Necesitas incluir la librería standard: `#include <stdlib.h>`. Puedes leer la [documentación](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html). Saludos

Comment: Otra opción, que no recordaba es `lrand48()` que devuelve un entero largo (`long`) pseudo aleatorio entre 0 y 2^31. Creo que con ese te alcanza. Saludos

Comment: Si por lo que lei Lrand48 me sirve mas, solo que no se como le puedo asignar a una variable un valor long. ``` #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { long lrand48(void); long x; x=lrand48(); return 0; } ``` hago eso pero me detecto lo errores, no se como se usa. ni que mas hacer

Comment: Es un poco complicado de explicar porqué, pero un problema es la declaración `long lrand48(void);` este **dentro** del bloque `{}` de `main()` _sin_ poner el necesario `extern` antes. Lo más sencillo: quita esta declaración, no es necesario, ya está incluida en `#include <stdlib.h>`. Otro posible problema es que esta función no existe en tu compilador C (se necesita una máquina UNIX).

Comment: probe en codeblock y dev c++ , y no me lo compilaron, ´´´long int x; 
 srand48(time(NULL));
 x=lrand48() ´´´ pero al usar el (https://www.jdoodle.com/) me compilo a la primera, eso fue raro ._.

Comment: CodeBlocks y DevC++ usan la biblioteca MinGW que no contiene la función `lrand48()`; por tanto da error. Posiblemente jdoodle.com corre en una máquina Linux y sí tiene esta función.

Comment: @AntoineL en efecto asi fue, otro que me compilo fue replit , y no se si en geany sirve , ya que no supe como instalarlo jejeje

Comment: OJO: lrand48() y drand48() no son aptos para seguridad. Si lo estas usando para generar un campo de valores aleatorios para una aplicacion grafica esta bien. Pero si es para algo de seguridad, es CRITICO usar una funcion segura como getrandom() en Unix o CryptGenRandom() en Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo único que tienes es rand() y RAND_MAX te devuelve un número de 16 bits (el ultimo bit es porque el mínimo es negativo). Entonces puedes generar un número de 32 bits así:

```
int num = 0;

num += rand()<< 16;
num += rand();
```

Si quieres limitarlo a de 0 a 2 millones entonces usa el módulo:

```
num = abs(num) % 2000000;
```